# IF statement in SQL Server around DBCC CHECKIDENT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create an `IF` statement or maybe even a case but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I have this:

```
DECLARE @var INT

SELECT @var = MAX(LeadAddressid)
FROM dbo.STG_LEAD_ADDRESS_BASE
WHERE LeadAddressid BETWEEN 600000000 AND 800000000

SET @var = @var + 1 

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('STG_LEAD_ADDRESS_BASE',RESEED, @var);
```

The condition I am trying to put is if the table is empty or no rows are returned I want the following code

```
 DBCC CHECKIDENT ('STG_LEAD_ADDRESS_BASE',RESEED, 600000000);
```

If there is a value in the table between 600000000 AND 80000000

Then I want the following:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('STG_LEAD_ADDRESS_BASE', RESEED, @var);
```

Can someone please advise how to do this in SQL Server? I have never used the `IF` statement in T-SQL - I am guessing that would be required?

Comment: There is uncovered case , what happens if the table has data Not between `600000000` AND `80000000` ?

Comment: And is this number correct or there is a missing zero ? `600000000` with 8 Zeros , `80000000` with 7 Zeros.

Comment: There shouldn't be as the total rows that can possibly reach shouldn't be anywhere near that for the life cycle, as there are 2 thousand rows per week. There shouldn't be a missing condition should there as that can't possibly happen?

Comment: Sorry its missing a zero, I will correct that now. I am just struggling with the logic of using IF Statement for it as Case would not recognise dbcc check ident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope it helps

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM dbo.STG_LEAD_ADDRESS_BASE
        WHERE LeadAddressid BETWEEN 600000000
                AND 800000000
        )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var BIGINT


    SELECT @var = MAX(LeadAddressid)
    FROM dbo.STG_LEAD_ADDRESS_BASE
    WHERE LeadAddressid BETWEEN 600000000
            AND 800000000

    --SET @var = @var + 1

    DBCC CHECKIDENT (
            'STG_LEAD_ADDRESS_BASE',
            RESEED,
            @var
            );
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DBCC CHECKIDENT (
            'STG_LEAD_ADDRESS_BASE',
            RESEED,
            600000000
            );
END
```

### Test Script

**Create Test Table**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Test_Table')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE Test_Table
GO

CREATE TABLE Test_Table (LeadAddressid INT IDENTITY(1, 1),SomeColumn VARCHAR(10))
GO
```

**Insert Script**

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM dbo.Test_Table
        WHERE LeadAddressid BETWEEN 600000000
                AND 800000000
        )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var BIGINT


    SELECT @var = MAX(LeadAddressid)
    FROM dbo.Test_Table
    WHERE LeadAddressid BETWEEN 600000000
            AND 800000000

    SET @var = @var

    DBCC CHECKIDENT (
            'Test_Table',
            RESEED,
            @var
            );
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DBCC CHECKIDENT (
            'Test_Table',
            RESEED,
            600000010
            );
END

INSERT INTO Test_Table
SELECT 'a'

SELECT * FROM Test_Table
```

First Run will Reseed the tables Identity to 600000000, Second run will reseed to 600000000 and the following insert will be 600000001, however if you were to inclement the variable, you would notice that the sequence would be 600000002 instead of 600000001. hope it helps.

Comment: Your welcome, please make sure you do not increment the variable (`SET @var = @var + 1`) by 1 as that will cause the sequence to jump on and cause gaps.

Comment: okay, I would have thought you would have to get the next identity? does it automatically pick the next one up?

Comment: Yes that's correct. i have added a test script you can use to see how it works. Adding it now

Comment: Happy to help. :)